# Flutter -Is creating global form state key is expensive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-textformfield

I am working with an application where I have multiple screens having input fields. I have to create multiple global form state key to validate each screen's form.

I heard that accessive use of global keys is not recommended. Is this true then how can i deal with validating multiple screen's forms without using large number of goobal form key??

Comment: *"I have to create multiple global form state key to validate each screen's form."* - you dont have to - you can use `Form.of` instead

Comment: @pskink any code snippet or examples for this?

Comment: `child: Form(
child: Column(
children: [
TextFormField(
validator: (s) => s!.length > 5? 'too long' : null,
),
Builder(
builder: (context) {
return ElevatedButton(onPressed: Form.of(context)!.validate, child: Text('validate'));
}
),
]
)
),
`

Answer (score 0):

A good method is to make your screens that contain validation `StateFullWidget` and define your formKey inside widget state;

Comment: I am doing the same now. Any better solutions than this?